# Shell Bash script that loops when writing to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to create a shell script that writes some configuration settings to a xml configuration file on Ubuntu. However, the settings are for an MQ cluster and I need the script to loop through a varying number of times (set by an input parameter) for each of the nodes that are being established.

The xml I would like to write to the file is:

```
    <listeners>
        <tcp-listener>
            <port>1883</port>
            <bind-address>10.0.0.4</bind-address>
        </tcp-listener>
    </listeners>
    <mqtt>
        <max-client-id-length>65535</max-client-id-length>
        <retry-interval>10</retry-interval>
        <max-queued-messages>1000</max-queued-messages>
    </mqtt>
    <cluster>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <transport>
            <tcp>
                <bind-address>10.0.0.4</bind-address>
                <bind-port>7800</bind-port>
            </tcp>
        </transport>
        <discovery>
            <static>
                <node>
                    <host>10.0.0.5</host>
                    <port>7800</port>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <host>10.0.0.6</host>
                    <port>7800</port>
                </node>
                <node> n times </node>
            </static>
        </discovery>
        <failure-detection>
            <heartbeat>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <interval>5000</interval>
                <timeout>15000</timeout>
            </heartbeat>
        </failure-detection>
    </cluster>
```

So basically, the number of `<node>` objects needs to reflect the variable the script takes in.

But, I am not sure how to loop through based on writing to the file. I was looking into using the tee command, but this doesn't let me loop though. I guess I could write the file up to the node object then loop through doing a write based on

Here is what I have so far that just writes static text:

```
tee /opt/hivemq/conf/config.xml > /dev/null <<'EOF'
     <the xml goes here>
exit 0
EOF
```

Is there a way to loop during the write? Or do I need to write up to the looped object, stop writing then have a loop that does multiple writes based on the loop counter, and then finally write the last bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'm still confused. What is the script supposed to loop through? What is supposed to be repeated in the output? Your XML sample is not a repeated pattern, as far as I can tell. Also you seem to have forgotten to finish a sentence in the third(?) paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

There's a command called 'seq' that you could use to help with iterating, so try something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

end=$1

(
    echo start

    for num in $(seq 1 $end)
    do
         node="10.0.0.$num"
         echo $node
    done

    echo end
) > out.xml
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question? btw, `seq` is useless and non-standard. And why a subshell?